# Facebook Javascript SDK causing extra margin/padding in responsive Twitter Bootstrap page in Firefox

Tags: css, facebook, html, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out why my pages based on Bootstrap responsive have an extra 25-30px on the right side **in Firefox and IE when the window is <600px in width.** I started to remove parts of my code one by one, until I was left only with the fluid nav bar and the Facebook SDK.  Once I then removed the Facebook JS SDK reference, the padding on the right side disappeared.

You can see this here:

FB JS SDK included, extra right side padding:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/571515/chewsy/Test/FB-with.htm

If you remove the FB JS SDK, it works as expected (no padding on right side):
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/571515/chewsy/Test/FB-without.htm

Since I need the Facebook JS SDK for the like buttons on my page, how can I work around this?

Oddly, in Safari and Chrome this does not repro.

Screenshot from Firefox:

[image]

Screenshot from IE:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any padding (Chrome 19)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the browser window needs to be resized to <600px width and only occurs in IE (tested with IE9) and Firefox (13).

Comment: Cannot reproduce in IE9 and FF as well. Everything looks normal

Comment: I just added 2 screenshots with what I'm seeing.

Comment: It was good on my work PC, good as well on home laptop (in both IE9 and FF13)

Comment: No issues here on Chrome or IE. You might want to try padding: 0; margin: 0; if you're still running into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by CBroe, you could *try* to alter the `#fb-root` style, but there may some JS actions that will change it again, or it may just disable some functions.

So I would suggest to add this to your styles :

```css
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

With this fix, you may encounter one slight problem if you have a very small window and want an horizontal scrollbar. You might try this, though the padding reappears under 200px :

```
@media (max-width: 200px) {
    html { overflow-x: auto; }
}
```

Tested on FF13, and IE9 (can't resize IE9 window to less than 200px).

Answer (score 0):

It’s the Facebook DIV element `#fb-root` that’s causing this – once you set it to `display:none` or position it `absolute`ly with say `left:-200px` via Firebug, the extra margin disappears.

However, doing so in your stylesheet might not be a good idea, since the SDK uses this element to display it’s dialogs etc. – so either those might stop working (setting it to `display:none` is supposed to stop it working in older IEs completely), or the SDK might overwrite such formatting again itself.

You should thoroughly test this, if you try adding formatting of your own to it.